# windows nic real-time priority

Tags: windows, networking

I have a Windows XP system with 2 NIC cards.  1 NIC card is used to just used to set some configuration to LabView. The other NIC is used to pump data real-time to another device using tcpip (not able to use UDP). The issue is that it cannot stop and rest for 125ms, once this happens we have problems.

The network we are on is pretty isolated, so nothing much is going on on the other NIC. Using Wireshark I can not correlate any event that happens on the other NIC, and do not see anything else with the Windows event logs.

Any ideas?

1. Is there a way to set the priority so that the real-time NIC doesn't get interrupted?
2. If nothing is going on, on the other NIC, and nothing is seen in the Windows event logs, what else could be going on to interrupt the real-time NIC?

Comment: As Windows XP isn't a realtime operating system, all kinds of things could interfere.  The thing just wasn't designed for this kind of duty.

Comment: Would linux be able to do what I want? If so what distribution is know for this type of duty?